# Just Don't Forget it

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You know who I am, and don't forget it.  And don't forget what I'm telling you now:

Years ago, I was in a similar place
So on this occasion I will treat you with grace
You have adorned yourself to match my creation
But let’s not forget your lower station

Your hands are your own, and that much is clear
But the work they may do gives me reason to fear
Keep them under wraps, and employ no device
No matter how much your mind is enticed

I will use no tools to intimidate,
My existence alone should make you hesitate
When you return, it best not be late
For- know it now- alone I will wait

If you want memories more than regrets
Then do not think these idle threats
Dance around the issue, but do no more
Or you’ll forever be met with a locked, closed door

Am I being too hard on you? Do you know who I am and what I am talking about?

Comment: Are u talking about universe?

Comment: @numberknot Nope. The intended answer is much smaller than the universe, but exists within it. But I would be interested in how the universe tied in to all these lines...

Comment: *I will use no tools to intimidate,
My existence alone should make you hesitate* Idk, but you certainly used fantastic wording here to intimidate me O_O

Comment: Perhaps it's our negative version of ourselves. All of our flaws and bad qualities formed as it's own personality?

Comment: @warspyking I suppose a wordsmith does use words as tools; I just do the best I can.  And you are somewhat on the right track, but not quite there yet.  I'll let a bit more time pass, then come up with a hint or another stanza.

Comment: And thanks to @NeedAName for posting a bounty on this question. I was afraid of muddying up the riddle with more stanzas or hints, but knew, given enough attention, the smart puzzlers on this site would crack it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Answer:**

> You are a father talking to a man who wishes to court your daughter

**Explanation (broken into parts):**

Intro

> You know who I am, and don't forget it. And don't forget what I'm telling you now: (the man wanting to court the daughter would at least be aware of the father's existence and would have reason to follow the father's council to stay on good terms with the family)

Lines 1-2

> Years ago, I was in a similar place. So on this occasion I will treat you with grace (the father would have once courted his own wife and had to have dealt with his wife's father, so the father will have at least some understanding of the man's intentions)

Lines 3-4

> You have adorned yourself to match my creation. But let’s not forget your lower station (the man has likely prepared himself to meet the father and appear worthy of the daughter, possibly by dressing up. The father considers the man to be of lower station than him in relation to the girl, considering he is the girl's father and the man has relatively little relation with the daughter up to this point)

Lines 5-6

> Your hands are your own, and that much is clear. But the work they may do gives me reason to fear (The father is expressing concern that the man may intend to have a sexual relationship with his possibly young or sheltered daughter)

Lines 7-8

> Keep them under wraps, and employ no device. No matter how much your mind is enticed (The father is instructing the man to avoid having a sexual relationship with his daughter despite temptations that exist)

Lines 9-10

> I will use no tools to intimidate, My existence alone should make you hesitate (I, for one, have definitely heard of fathers hinting at threats with baseball bats or shotguns (tools) over their daughters, but this father appears to be different. In any case, if the man is young the father is likely intimidating even without tools. If the man is a bit older and has intentions of a serious relationship, he probably wants to stay on the family's good side.

Lines 11-12

> When you return, it best not be late. For- know it now- alone I will wait (Don't keep my daughter out later than curfew, or whatever time you said you'd bring her back. If you do, the father will almost certainly be up worried and waiting, and likely very angry)

Lines 13-14

> If you want memories more than regrets, Then do not think these idle threats (If you want a long lasting relationship where you can build memories together, you probably don't want to be going behind the father's back, who appears to believe he has the ability to prevent a relationship between the two (again, possibly because the daughter and suitor are both young))

Lines 15-16

> Dance around the issue, but do no more, Or you’ll forever be met with a locked, closed door (if the man doesn't follow the father's council he will quite literally be met with a closed door when the father will prevent his daughter (who appears to be still living with the family) from seeing him)

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.se  Please add an explanation to your answer.  You can refer to answers to other riddles for a good format.  An answer without an explanation may be deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I will add one momentarily. I tried to add an explanation earlier, but could not figure out the syntax to make a multi-line spoiler with line breaks in it - is that possible?

Comment: Only time will tell if this is correct, but after reading your explanations, I'm convinced. +1

Comment: @Porthos3 - Great, thanks.  For a multi-line spoiler, use 2 spaces or <br> at the end of each line. Then another >! at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head; nicely explained for all parts.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Great answer, and you explained it perfectly.

Comment: @Porthos well done, I can't award the bounty for another 8 hours it seems, but I'll be sure to award it once I'm able.

Comment: @NeedAName, It appears I have already been awarded the points for the bounty. I don't know why the bounty message is still there. Thank you!